# Trying to make a backup drive hot swappable

Tags: 16.04, mount, hard-drive, backup, fstab

I have a removable HDD caddy with 2 HDD.
Created a backup list in crontab.
Have edited my fstab to include.

```
#Hot swappable 1
UUID=1CCA415ECA4134F4   /media/drivebay ntfs    auto,nofail     0       0

#Hot swappable 2
UUID=2E5403865403504F   /media/drivebay ntfs    auto,nofail     0       0
```

I have added to crontab before any backup code

```
sudo mount -a
```

First drive worked perfectly, but when I remove HDD1 and install HDD2 its not mounted.

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

I've included in the crontab prior to any backup the following

```
sudo umount /media/drivebay
sudo mount -a
```